# mvtnorm installation in R, error trying to exec gfortran-4.2 Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: r, macos, gfortran

I have just installed R using brew and try to install mvtnorm package, but I get the following error:
Any suggestions how to solve this?

```
> install.packages("mvtnorm")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.1/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.1-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 166202 bytes (162 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 162 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mvtnorm’ ...
** package ‘mvtnorm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.1.0/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/xz/include -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wno-implicit-function-declaration  -c miwa.c -o miwa.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c mvt.f -o mvt.o
gfortran-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/local/bin/i686-apple-darwin8-gfortran-4.2': execvp: Bad CPU type in executable
make: *** [mvt.o] Error 255
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvtnorm’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.1/site-library/mvtnorm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4l/y1pqv07934x_2qv3bzj_93s40000gn/T/RtmpHUys7l/downloaded_packages’
>
```

Comment: Gfortran 4.2 is **ancient**, where did you get it? What OS is this? I suggest updating your GCC. Try homebrew or something.

Comment: Actually, I don't know. I just installed R and could not install the package and see the message. > R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin20.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin20.4.0

Comment: In that case install gfortran of your own.

Comment: macOS Big Sur Version 11.4

Comment: OK, the gfortran you have is probably incompatible. Try to install a different one. Try homebrew.

Comment: I tried 'brew upgrade gfortran' and get  'Warning: gfortran 11.1.0_1 already installed'

Comment: Thanks, but I still can not install that package.

Comment: Well, I do not use Mac. Unfortunately, the number of users having messy problems with Fortran compilers on mac is disproportionately high. I cannot help you with this OS, but some other users might.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I installed gfortran 10.2 (thanks to https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/issues/17) now I am able to install mvtnorm and some other packages having the same problem.